# jQuery value of radio button: "Uncaught syntax error, unrecognized expression"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the value of a radio button with `$("input[@name=login]")`, but am getting "Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression".

See http://jsfiddle.net/fwnUm/ and here's the code in full:

```
<!-- Radio buttons to choose signin/register -->
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-theme="z" data-type="horizontal" >
    <input type="radio" name="login" id="radio-signin" value="signin" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio-signin">Signin</label>
    <input type="radio" name="login" id="radio-register" value="register" />
    <label for="radio-register">Register</label>
</fieldset>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("input[@name=login]").change(function(){
      alert($("input[@name=login]:checked").val());
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XPath-like attribute selectors were removed in jQuery 1.3.  (We're now on jQuery 1.6.)

Just remove the `@`:

```
$("input[name='login']").change(function(){
  alert($("input[name='login']:checked").val());
});
```

Note that quote marks are also required.

[See the API reference for the attribute equals selector.](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector)

Comment: When did they start requiring quotes? 1.6?

Comment: @Matt Since forever, AFAIK.  Generally your code will *work* without them, but they are nonetheless technically mandatory.

Comment: See the [API page](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector): **Quotes are mandatory.**

Comment: @lonesomeday, you is right, the docs say it. In fact I can't agree with the docs. How can anything be mandatory if it isn't required to works? Lol. BTW, I never wrote a code that haven't worked without the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@`. `$("input[name=login]")`

You probably also want to use `this` in the callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("input[name=login]").change(function(){
      alert($(this).val());
    });     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `$("input[name=login]")` works for me. Never seen the `@` used in that context before, is it supposed to be doing something?

Answer (score 0):

Lose the @ symbol in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `@` symbol from your selectors, since it doesn't exists on jQuery 1.5.2.

Here is your Fiddle [updated](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/fwnUm/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the attribute value, 'login'. Also, I don't think you need the @ symbol:

```
 $("input[name='login']").change(function(){
      alert($("input[name='login']:checked").val());
   });
```